Faicons and ternary operator not working in react for this code
whenever i try to see the icon it's not showing is this logic correct? in my app what thing i am missing?
faRegHeart is working for icon but for this logic it hide when i wrote in classname for ternary logic
this is what i am facing in this code if you can help me out it good for me to learn this stuff
my  package.json file for react-icons in the dependencies section is perfect.
tailwind is also working fine
functionality is also working in terminal
true false
in console
import { FaRegHeart } from 'react-icons/fa';

const Blog = () => {
  const [heart, setHeartClick] = useState(false);

  const handleHeartClick = () => {
    setHeartClick(!heart);
    console.log(heart);
  };

  return (
    <>
        <FaRegHeart 
          onClick={handleHeartClick} 
          className={`${heart ? "text-red" : "text-white"}`} 
        />
    
    </>
  );
}

export default Blog;```



Have you confirmed in the element inspector if the class changes? If it does change, the problem is with the CSS. Have you defined rules for text-red and text-white classes in your CSS?

If you just want to change color of icon you can do like below instead.
For applying to outlined icon -
<FaRegHeart 
    onClick={handleHeartClick} 
    color={heart ? "red" : "white"}
/>

If you want to apply background color, use filled icon type, For example -
<FaHeart 
    onClick={handleHeartClick} 
    color={heart ? "red" : "white"}
/>


whenever i remove this part only take this it show icon

otherwise it show blank when i implement your code

also how to do for background-color

You can choose filled icon instead of outlined icon, this will work with same above code. I have also edited my answer for this.
